# Can a 0/0 creature with +1/+1 counters on it (like a Hydra) be regenerated?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-regenerate

Since I fairly new to the Regeneration deal I have a question about regenerating Hydra creatures with +1/+1 counters on them. My friend seems to think that if he [Doom Blade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Doom%20Blade)s, [Supreme Verdict](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Supreme%20Verdict)s, or any destroy creatures/target creature on my side of the field, that I can't use the regeneraton effect from [Golgari Charm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Golgari%20Charm) on my [Primordial Hydra](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Primordial%20Hydra) or [Savageborn Hydra](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Savageborn%20Hydra). He thinks that they become 0/0's and the counters thus go away so regenerating a Hydra with no +1/+1 counters on it since I cant recast it means my Hydras are dead. Is this correct?

Comment: some of the confusion here may well be a result of the card Protean Hydra, which would behave exactly in the way your friend described if it had 3 +1/+1 counters on it and was targeted with lightning bolt.

Answer (score 16):

Those two spells Destroy. Regeneration replaces destruction, which means the destruction doesn't happen, which means it doesn't cause anything to go to the graveyard. If you cast the regeneration mode of Golgari Charm in response to Doom Blade or Supreme Verdict, your Hydras will be safe. They will not lose counters, enchantments, or equipment; they don't gain summoning sickness; spells targeting them don't lose sight of them; LTB and ETB abilities don't trigger; etc.

> 614.8. Regeneration is a destruction-replacement effect. The word “instead” doesn’t appear on the card but is implicit in the definition of regeneration. “Regenerate [permanent]” means “The next time [permanent] would be destroyed this turn, instead remove all damage marked on it and tap it. If it’s an attacking or blocking creature, remove it from combat.” Abilities that trigger from damage being dealt still trigger even if the permanent regenerates. See rule 701.12.

Regeneration will not save the Hydras from being sent to the graveyard as a result of having non-positive toughness, but nothing in the scenario you gave reduces their toughness (by removing +1/+1 counters or otherwise).

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I will be making room for those Golgari Charms after all.

Answer (score 7):

I think the confusion stems from a belief that regeneration causes the creature to leave the battlefield, but come back(like persist does).

But the rules just says to remove the damage and remove the creature from combat **Instead** of destroying it(it's a replacement effect).  It is continuously on the battlefield during the entire process.

Comment: Your comment makes me think a "resurrection shield" (akin to persist/undying) would be a cool, if confusing mechanic.

Comment: "Gains persist/undying until end of turn" kind of does it, I suppose.

Comment: @corsiKa [Cauldron of Souls](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=446916) is one example that kind of does exactly that.

Comment: @Andrew No, it doesn't. Cauldron grants persist, where it comes back with a -1/-1 counter. Same with [Undying Evil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=262835) which grants undying. My suggestion was something that does the same thing but without any sort of counter. Simple, pure resurrection until end of turn.